# SQL Query duplicating values even using Distinct

Tags: php

My query seems to be duplicating the values that are being displayed.
I don't understand why, I have 5 tables
products with an id and category (4 of them), then each category is related to another table where the product_name, price is, then each one of these tables is related to the table called stock, stock is the one where price is.

```
`
  <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "", "db_login");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    $sql = "SELECT products.id, products.category, hygiene.product_name, hygiene.price, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN hygiene ON products.id = hygiene.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON hygiene.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Hygiene'

UNION

SELECT products.id, products.category, food.product_name, food.price, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN food ON products.id = food.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON food.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Food'

UNION

SELECT products.id, products.category, toys.product_name, toys.price, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN toys ON products.id = toys.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON toys.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Toys'

UNION

SELECT products.id, products.category, clothes.product_name, clothes.price, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN clothes ON products.id = clothes.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON clothes.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Clothes'";


$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  
    $product_name = isset($row['product_name']) ? $row['product_name'] : '';
    $quantity = isset($row['quantity']) ? $row['quantity'] : '';
    $price = isset($row['price']) ? $row['price'] : '';
    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<form name='update' action='update_stock.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='product_name' value='".$row ['product_name']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='stock--update--num' name='quantity' value='".$row['quantity']."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='stock--update--num' name='price' value='".$row['price']. "€"."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='Update'></td>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

    ?>
  </table>`
```

I wanted for it to display each item only once with the correct quantity and price.

Other code I tried:

```
`$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:3307", "root", "", "db_login");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT products.*, hygiene.product_id, hygiene.product_name, hygiene.price, hygiene.image_path, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN hygiene ON products.id = hygiene.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON hygiene.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Hygiene'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT products.*, food.product_id, food.product_name, food.price, food.image_path, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN food ON products.id = food.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON food.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Food'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT products.*, toys.product_id, toys.product_name, toys.price, toys.image_path, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN toys ON products.id = toys.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON toys.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Toys'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT products.*, clothes.product_id, clothes.product_name, clothes.price, clothes.image_path, stock.quantity
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN clothes ON products.id = clothes.product_id
LEFT JOIN stock ON clothes.product_id = stock.item_id
WHERE products.category = 'Clothes'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<form name='update' action='update_stock.php' method='post'>";

    $product_name = isset($row['product_name']) ? $row['product_name'] : '';
    $quantity = isset($row['quantity']) ? $row['quantity'] : '';
    $price = isset($row['price']) ? $row['price'] : '';

    echo "<td><input type='text' name='product_name' value='".$product_name."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='stock--update--num' name='quantity' value='".$quantity."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='stock--update--num' name='price' value='".$price. "€"."'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='Update'></td>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</tr>";
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your UNION queries in one single DISTINCT query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(
SELECT...
UNION
SELECT....
UNION
SELECT...
)
```

But looking at your query closely, you are querying for more columns than you are fetching - I don't think product_ids would make a unique result.

Comment: UNION implicitly does DISTINCT already, this is superfluous

Comment: Two answear both commends, even with that single distinct I get duplicate values. And secondly I had to try using DISTINCT on top of UNION because UNION alone was also causing duplicates.

Comment: It will return duplicates - modify each sub query to return product_name, quantity and price ONLY - those are the only columns you are displaying.